# How to send multiple Formdata in one single array to express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to send multiple form data as an array to my express backend. But if i create an array of formdata i get an empty object on express. Even the payload on network tab is empty.

```
let arr1 = {data: []}

let data1 = new FormData()
data1.append('name': 'somename')
data1.append('age': 20)

let data2 = new FormData()
data2.append('name': 'somename')
data2.append('age': 20)

arr1.data.push(data1)
arr1.data.push(data2)
```

Is there any possible work around except hitting the api for every form data.

Comment: if you log arr1 after pushing, what do you get?

Comment: Is it a typo: `data1.append('name': 'somename')` you have a `:` instead of comma?

Comment: I took another array inside arr1 object. Like arr1 = {data: []}. So finally i got this:   


`
         data: 
            0: FormData {}
            1: FormData {}
         }
`

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you please see the code

```
var arr1 = []

var data1 = {name:'ABC',age:20}
var data2 = {name:'ABC1',age:21}

arr1.push(data1)
arr1.push(data2)


console.log(arr1)
```